# Playstore issue in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to build apk , but I am unable to upload app to play store which gives me error as  "Your uploaded apk or android app bundle with invalid or missing signing info.you need to create a valid signed apk or android app bundle"

Comment: You need to do some research about signing an apk.

Comment: this this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038209/5909026