# Upload failed in play store

Tags: ionic-framework

I am unable to upload app into play store using ionic v1.... error is  "Your uploaded apk or Android app bundle with invalid or missing signing info. you need to create a validly signed apk or Android app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Keystore file   and again generate your APK using valid keystore

Answer (score 0):

GUIDE TO PUBLISH YOUR APPLICATION:

Step 1).

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore “my-release-key.keystore “ –alias  “alias_name”   -keyalg  RSA   -keysize  2048  -validity 10000
```

·         my-release-key.keystore: path to keystore

·         example: D:\projects\path\to\your\project\KeystoreName.keystore

·         “alias_name” : Name of your project

Step 2).

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

Step 3).

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore D:\project\path\to\your\project/keystoreName.keystore D:\projects\path\to\your\project\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk alias_name
```

Step 4). inside your sdk buildtool folder

```
zipalign -v 4 D:\projects\path\to\your\project\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk D:\projects\path\to\your\project\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\Zipalign.apk
```