# Which are the steps to follow for building an APK?

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework

So, what the title says, I already coded my app, but I wanna build an APK from it, and install it into my phone (Android), I read the documentation about the subject but I am lost.

Could someone explain to me in an easy way what to do? I use Windows.

I only try using cordova, as the Ionic documentation says, when I use this command 'ionic cordova prepare android', I get an error thay says that cordova does not support Vue.js or somwthing like that

Comment: Check This also for building and uploading on play store: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55038209/5909026

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to first import your project to Android studio

**To import**

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open the `platform/android` folder of your project in Android Studio

**To Build**

1. Navigate from the toolbar `Build -> Generate Signed Apk`
2. Create your Key file (you will need to save this key file for future updates)
3. Select `release` and `V1 and V2 signature` variants and off you go..

> Don't forget that you will need to first build your Cordova project
>   using `cordova build android` command before executing the above
>   steps.

You can find detailed documentation on from the [Cordova Official Documentation.](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I can't execute the command `cordova build android` because it causes the following message: Current working directory is not a Cordava-based project.

Comment: This is a typical error when you copy folders or in other words did not use `cordova cli` to create the project. Try to create the project using `cordova create app com.app` and that should resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can read this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-a-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface)

it's very useful for building APK's and sign them

Answer (score -1):

Steps to build debug APK for testing:

1). Add Android Platform  `ionic cordova platform add android`

2). Connect your phone(enable Developer Mode from settings) and run `ionic cordova run android`  // this will build and install directly in your device.

3). When app starts open Chrome and inspect your application and debug it.