# Ionic Cordova run Android and... Go Store?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

My question is basically the title.

Suppose that I already have the application that I have programmed, finished and tested. I just run this command line

```
ionic cordova run android
```

then... I'm going to

> platforms \ android \ app \ build \ outputs \ apk \ debug \

Rename app-debug.apk and ... Ready? Can I upload this APK to Google Store? Or is it necessary to do something else? Or is there any additional good practice that you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload failed in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035972/upload-failed-in-play-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the documentation for publishing your app on android :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/play-store

And the same for Ios:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/app-store

Answer (score 0):

first you should create release version and then sign it ,
you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-a-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface) and it shows detailed steps to create keystore and release apk and sign it .